# React-big-calendar issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, helper, date-fns, react-big-calendar

I am using react big calendar library for learning purposes, anyway, it's seems not to be working well. I have followed the proper steps using date-fns, but the issue is that the information is not being displayed, the year appears as "yyyy" and the days of the week remains shown as "cccc", besides that is not displaying the time, and each respective number of the day either.

Here is my repo so you can take a look if you want to: https://github.com/K1mera/Calendar

Anyway, I am pase it my code here as well:

```
import { Calendar } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";

import { addHours } from "date-fns";
import { localizer, getMessages } from "../../helpers";

import { NavBar, CalendarEvent } from "../../calendar"


const events = [{
  title: 'bla',
  notes: 'dsfsafasdfs',
  start: new Date(),
  end: addHours( new Date(), +2),
  bgColor: '',
  user: {
    id: '22',
    name: 'Jhonny Se'
  }
}]


export const CalendarPage = () => {

  const getEventStyle = ( event, start, end, isSelected ) => {
    
  }

  return (
    <main className="bg-slate-50">
      <NavBar />
      <Calendar
        culture="en-US"
        localizer={ localizer }
        events={ events }
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        style={{ height: "calc( 100vh - 80px )" }}
        messages={ getMessages() }
        eventPropGetter={ getEventStyle }
        components={{
          event: CalendarEvent,
        }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

This is a helper I created to clean the code in my calendar component:

```
import { dateFnsLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";

import { format, parse, startOfWeek, getDay } from "date-fns";
import  enUS  from "date-fns/locale/en-US";

const locales = {
  "en-US": enUS,
};

export const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
  format,
  parse,
  startOfWeek,
  getDay,
  locales,
});
```

Appreciate the help very much!!

I tried looking for previous questions, bot none of them were related with my issue. Chat gpt recommeded me to clean cache, and remove the date-fns, package, but nopthng have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The formats, generated by the localizers, are preset. You can override any of them by providing override methods to the different `formats` functions. There are examples of overriding any of these within the Big Calendar documentation.

```js
// this one is using the moment localizer, so you might
// need to adjust your format tokens for the localizer
// of your choice
const { defaultDate, formats, views } = useMemo(
  () => ({
    defaultDate: new Date(2015, 3, 13),
    formats: {
      dayHeaderFormat: (date, culture, localizer) =>
        localizer.format(date, 'dddd MMMM Do', culture),
    },
    views: [Views.WEEK, Views.DAY],
  }),
  []
)
```